# In vim, how to highlight a line while keeping syntax coloring?

Tags: vim

In vim, I want to:

- highlight a single line (e.g. `:hi CursorLine ctermbg=black`)

AND

- maintain syntax highlighting

AND

- not set up any custom color themes or similar

(note: adding a few lines to .vimrc is fine)

---

I've tried setting via `:hi CursorLine ctermbg=black`, but this results in changing the cursor highlight color but not maintaining syntax coloring.

not highlighted, and has syntax coloring:

[image: not highlighted but syntax]

highlighted, but loses syntax coloring:

[image: highlighted and no syntax]

in above example, I would want the `string` word to stay purple, `if` word stay yellow, etc., even though line is highlighted.

---

I also tried toggling `:syntax off` `:syntax on`, and not surprisingly this had no effect.

---

[This question (Syntax highlighting in vim)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421022/syntax-highlighting-in-vim) seems similar to what I'm asking, but it's not because 1) I don't want to change the background, 2) I don't want to change theme, 3) it seems like OP here was having trouble with existing syntax color scheme and just wanted to be able to see things.

[This question (Custom syntax coloring vim)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841314/custom-syntax-coloring-vim) seems similar to what I'm asking, but it's not because 1) I don't want to change existing syntax coloring, I want to keep it, 2) I don't want to add arbitrary syntax highlighting, I just want CursorLine to be highlighted while also maintaining syntax coloring.

Comment: Can't reproduce this... What does Vim tell you when you check the highlight configuration with `:hi CursorLine`? Are the other attributes cleared? If not, you can clear them by setting them to NONE, e.g. `:hi CursorLine ctermfg=NONE`. Or if you have `cterm=reverse` then you're actually setting the foreground color with `ctermbg`... Reset that with `cterm=NONE` too.

Comment: @filbranden I ran `:hi CursorLine` and got `CursorLine     xxx term=underline cterm=underline guibg=Grey40`. I then solved this by doing `:hi CursorLine ctermbg=black term=none cterm=none`. Not exactly what you said, but that pointed me in the right direction, so thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my desired behavior by running `:hi CursorLine ctermbg=black term=none cterm=none`.

And while out of scope of my original question, running `:set cursorline` is also needed for the line highlighting to be displayed.

Comment: This worked for me too since I used a pre-made theme that had the `call s:h("CursorLine", {"bg": s:bg_color_value})` set up. So all I needed to do was have `set cursorline` added to my vimrc file.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me ...

`:hi CursorLine cterm=NONE guifg=NONE`